# maximum update depth exceeded when updating a state variable in React

Tags: reactjs

The problem im having is when I try to call setState in the handleIncrement function i get maximum update depth exceeded even though this is the only time that I am calling it (not using lifecycles). I have tried moving around the method to see if its a bug with react

```
class Counter extends Component {
    state = {
        count: 0,
        tags: ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']


    };

    handleIncrement = () => {

        this.setState({count: this.state.count+1});
    };
    render() {

        let classes = this.getBadgeClasses();
        return (
            <div>
                <span className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>{this.state.count}</span>
                <button onClick={this.handleIncrement()} className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Increment</button>
                <ul>
                    {this.state.tags.length === 0 && "Please create a new tag"}
                    {this.renderTags()}

                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onClick={this.handleIncrement()}
```

You are calling your `handleIncrement` function on render, and passing the result to the `onClick` prop. So it renders, updates state, state has changed, so it renders, which updates the state...

You probably want

```
onClick={() => this.handleIncrement()}
```

or

```
onClick={this.handleIncrement}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `onClick` of button element - you are calling the function instead of passing the function name itself. That causes it to change the state repeatedly and the error is caused.

Try changing it to - `this.handleIncrement`